# Why does this work? Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, overloading

I have a program with this line of code:

```
factArg = QInputDialog::getInt(0, "Some text",
        "Some more text", 1);
```

and it works. But when I look at the documentation it says that this is how we have to use the function getInt();

```
int QInputDialog::getInt(QWidget * parent, const QString & title, 
const QString & label, int value = 0, int min = -2147483647, int max = 2147483647, 
int step = 1, bool * ok = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0) [static]
```

as you can see there are a whole lot more arguments in the documentation, and nowhere in the documentation do I see anything about this function being overloaded.

So is this function overloaded and it's just not documented or is it something you can do in C++ i.e does C++ allow you to leave out some arguments and it sort of figures out the best way for it to make sense? If so, what rules does the compiler follow?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

Comment: As you can also clearly see there are default values specified for the parameters, thus you can omit them.

Comment: it is not "function overloading" but "default arguments" at play

Answer (score 2):

That's how works default parameters in C++. Here is a minimal example introducing this:

```
int foo( int param1, int param2 = 6 )
{
    std::cout << param1 << "-" << param2 << std::endl;
}
```

`foo( 3 )` displays "3 - 6" (6 being the default value for `param2` when not specified by caller

`foo( 3, 8 )` displays "3 - 8"

Comment: I actually just realised that minutes after posting the question! Oops